# Manipulate SQL dataframe with python script in Power BI

Tags: python, sql, powerbi, powerquery, m

I'd like to execute a simple python script in Power BI on a SQL dataframe.
But the error seems to indicate like the SQL table has been read as a CSV file and I don't know why the script consider the dataframe as a CSV file instead of an SQL dataframe as it is.

The python script is : 
`import pandas as pd`  
`dataset['COD-MARQ'] = dataset['COD-MARQ'].str.strip()`

Any ideas on how shoud I process ?

thanks

[image]

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PythonScriptWrapper.PY", line 7, in <module>
    df1 = pandas.read_csv('input_df_da064532-6620-4e48-a091-ff580b127759.csv')
  File "C:\Users\afalieres\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 686, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\afalieres\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 458, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\afalieres\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1186, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\afalieres\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2145, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 847, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 862, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 941, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1073, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1119, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1194, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1814, in pandas._libs.parsers._try_int64
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 64.0 KiB for an array with shape (8192,) and data type int64

Détails :
    DataSourceKind=Python
    DataSourcePath=Python
    Message=Ρŷтнőŋ şсŗĩрţ εггǿŗ.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PythonScriptWrapper.PY", line 7, in <module>
    df1 = pandas.read_csv('input_df_da064532-6620-4e48-a091-ff580b127759.csv')
  File "C:\Users\afalieres\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 686, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\afalieres\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 458, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\afalieres\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1186, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\afalieres\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2145, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 847, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 862, in pandas._libs.parsers.Tex...
    ErrorCode=-2147467259
    ExceptionType=Microsoft.PowerBI.Scripting.Python.Exceptions.PythonScriptRuntimeException ```
````

Comment: Can you post the last few lines of traceback where error tends to show?

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! I updated the post with the entire error message. I hope it'll help you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive it's the problem, but it looks to me like the `dataset` is referring to the previous step rather than the original source, which means it's no longer in a SQL dataframe format. You probably want to either import the original source using python or else modify your script to treat the dataset not as a SQL dataframe but in whatever format the Query Editor passes to the python script (which *I think* is a pandas dataframe).

On a separate note, in this particular case, it seems unnecessary to use python for a simple transformation that can just as easily be done natively in M.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! I'm new on Power BI. The original source is a SQL dataframe and I want to apply a bigger Python script on it. This line is just a test. I imported the SQL dataframe clicking on "Get Data" then "SQL Azure database"